# How to query exact match for one-to-many in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I have two tables T1 and T2 with one-to-many relation from T1 to T2. Suppose I want to search for rows in T1 that exactly matched queried rows in T2.

For example,

**Table T1**

| id |
| --- |
| x1 |
| x2 |

**Table T2**

| id | t1_id |
| --- | --- |
| y1 | x1 |
| y2 | x1 |
| y4 | x2 |
| y5 | x2 |

When I am querying y1 and y1 it shouldn't return x1. Similarly, if I query y1 and y4 then also it shouldn't return anything. Only when I query exactly y1 and y2 exactly, it should return x1. And when I query y4 and y5 it should return x2.

What I've done is use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to concat T2 by the id of T1
and checked search terms all matches GROUP_CONCAT. My query looks something like

```sql
SELECT t1_id
FROM T2 
GROUP BY t1_id 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id)='y1y2'
```

Although it gets the job done, I don't think it is the most efficient way for doing this. There should be better way, considering it's such a common problem. I couldn't find proper terms to search in other threads.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1_id
FROM table2
GROUP BY t1_id
HAVING HAVING SUM(t2.t1_id IN ('y4', 'y5')) = COUNT(t2.t1_id)
```

The query ignores the rows where `t1_id IS NULL`. If you need the rows with NULL to be absent then use `COUNT(*)`.

The query does not check if the value which is not present in a table is present in the input list. I.e. if input list is `('y1', 'y2', 'y3')` then `x1` will be returned despite the fact that the value `'y3'` is not in the table.